# VSTS (Azure DevOps) builds suddenly failing

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Getting this issue for builds which used to succeed "Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client."

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add an explicit version against the package reference `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` should look like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />`

Additionally, make sure the pipeline is not targeting the 'Latest' version of Visual Studio in the build pipeline but the version which is being used during development... in my case 2017

[image]

Microsoft add new versions of Visual Studio into that drop down list